# Python Join with characters at the beginning and end

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written this code in python

```
import os
files = os.listdir(".")
x = ""
for file in files:
  x = ("\"" + file + "\" ")

f = open("files.txt", "w")
f.write(x)
f.close()
```

this works and I get a single string with all the files in a directory as `"foo.txt" "bar.txt" "baz.txt"`

but I don't like the for loop. Can't I write the code more succinctly.... like those python pros?

I tried

`"\"".join(files)`

but how do I get the `"` the end of the file name as well?

Comment: more importantly perhaps why would you want that? (the quote marks I mean)

Comment: doesn't  `"\"".join(files) + "\""` give what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can write string literals using both `'single'` and `"double-quotes"`; you don't have to escape one inside the other.
2. You can use the `format` function to apply quotes before you `join`.
3. You should use the `with` statement when opening files to save you from having to `close` it explicitly.

Thus:

```
import os
with open("files.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(' '.join('"{}"'.format(file) for file in os.listdir('.'))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import os
files = os.listdir(".")
x = " ".join('"%s"'%f for f in files)
with open("files.txt", "w") as f:    
    f.write(x)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `with` to writer file.

```
import os
files = os.listdir('.')
x = ' '.join(['"%s"'%f for f in files])
with open("files.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(x)
```